# Entity Framework Core 2.0 CRUD best practices / automation

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

Are there established best practices for a CRUD in EF Core 2.0?

Is there any way to automatically generate CRUDs for the models, preferably using these best practices?

As an example, this is what I have currently, but I have to replicate it to something like 20 other entities:

```
[Route("entities")]
public class EntitiesController : Controller
{
    private readonly ProjectContext _context;

    public EntitiesController(ProjectContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Post([FromBody]Entities entity)
    {
        _context.Add(entity);
        return Json(await _context.SaveChangesAsync() >= 1);
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public JsonResult Get(int? entityId)
    {
        if (entityId == null)
            return Json(_context.Entities.Select(x => x));
        else
            return Json(_context.Entities.FirstOrDefault(x => x.EntityId == entityId));
    }

    [HttpPut]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Put([FromBody]Entities entity)
    {
        if (entity.EntityId < 1)
            return BadRequest();

        _context.Entities.Update(entity);
        return Json(await _context.SaveChangesAsync() >= 1);
    }

    [HttpDelete]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Delete(int entityId)
    {
        if (entityId < 1)
            return BadRequest();

        Entities entity = _context.Entities.Where(x => x.EntityId == entityId).FirstOrDefault();
        if (entity == null)
            return BadRequest();

        _context.Entities.Remove(entity);
        return Json(await _context.SaveChangesAsync() >= 1);
    }
}
```

Comment: you should have a look at the repository pattern. Doesn't answer the part about automation, but will probably help you. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions/getting-started-with-ef-5-using-mvc-4/implementing-the-repository-and-unit-of-work-patterns-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application .

Comment: My first observation in your code is you should never get the context to your service project. it should stay in the repository layer. the service should only send request to  businessmanager and business manager will talk to repository.

Comment: @Pac0 **Don't**, EF is already a Repository, do not hide it yet behind another Repository.

Comment: Have you looked at the ASP.NET Core's autogenerated CRUD's? They are not the best, but fast to implement views/controllers

Comment: Nop. Where can I look them up?

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto I'd like to disagree. EF is kind of a repository, but not satisfactorily enough when it comes to unit testing, for instance. Microsoft itself suggests that you use a repository in between your ASP controller and EF. (see link)

Comment: @MatheusLacerda You can look at them by using right-click on the Controller's folder and following the scaffolding wizard (`Add Controller` > `MVC Controller with views, using EF`).

Comment: @Pac0 I second that. There are other logic in the repository like generic logging and dynamic SQL building and so on.

Comment: You still can *Moq* DbContext using InMemory DbContext, but still Repository pattern is recommended. 1) You can replace EF with other ORM. 2) Service class get's rid of another responsibility, which is interacting with database.

Comment: @Pac0 I've been using EF InMemoryDb for testing which is pretty great. Hiding EF is a real maintenance pain.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto Oh, that! lol
Well, there must be a better solution...

Comment: And you should use dependency injection to inject business manager to service and repository to business manager

Answer (score 5):

There is an insightful [article in Micorosoft's website](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/microservices-architecture/microservice-ddd-cqrs-patterns/infrastructure-persistence-layer-implemenation-entity-framework-core). In this article, they have defined some of the best practices. For example there is a controversial debate about using DbContext directly or a repository and they have addressed this issue as follows:

> The Entity Framework DbContext class is based on the Unit of Work and
>   Repository patterns, and can be used directly from your code, such as
>   from an ASP.NET Core MVC controller. That is the way you can create
>   the simplest code, as in the CRUD catalog microservice in
>   eShopOnContainers. In cases where you want the simplest code possible,
>   you might want to directly use the DbContext class, as many developers
>   do.
>
> However, implementing custom repositories provides several benefits
>   when implementing more complex microservices or applications. The Unit
>   of Work and Repository patterns are intended to encapsulate the
>   infrastructure persistence layer so it is decoupled from the
>   application and domain model layers. Implementing these patterns can
>   facilitate the use of mock repositories simulating access to the
>   database.

So, as the first step maybe you should change the way you are using Dbcontext and use repositories instead of that. There are many more points and hints in this article.

Comment: I can understand the use of repositories for simulating purposes or in case of changing the data provider, however, unit of work is totally implemented inside ef with keeping tracks of queries and execute them in an atomic sql transaction, why would I need that, I didn't get it.